PDFDocumentWriteOption PDFDocumentSaveTextFromOCROption is not working?
I am trying to create PDF from the scan images. I want to enable to select the Text from image after PDF creation. I had tried below code but its not working.
if (@available(iOS 16.0, *)) {
    
    NSDictionary *dict = @{
        PDFDocumentTitleAttribute: @"Sample PDF",
        PDFDocumentAuthorAttribute: @"Author Name",
        PDFDocumentSaveTextFromOCROption: @YES,
    };
    
    [ocrPDFDocument writeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePDFPath] withOptions:dict];
    
    [self.delegate pdfOCR:self didPDFOcrFileAtPath:savePDFPath];
    
}

PDFDocumentSaveTextFromOCROption is not applied after creating PDF.
Does any one have idea.?
